# 1D -> 2D Array W/Normal Curve Sub-Array Lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, gaussian, splice, batching

I am trying to break a 1D array into a 2D array where the sub-arrays are of varying lengths. This variance should follow the gaussian curve [or a mound shape]. So, say the 2D array variable we make is named gaussianCurve.  The array within gaussianCurve[0] & gaussianCurve[n] would be of length 1, and gaussianCurve[n/2] would be a maximum provided by a parameter "maxArrayLength". This forces the number of gaussianCurve indexes to become variable.

Say I have the following psuedo-code:

```
function (oneDimentionalArray, maxArrayLength) {
// oneDimentionalArray is ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]
// maxArrayLength is 5
// Currently working like this (i.e. "batches"):
// return [["A","B","C","D","E"],["F","G","H","I","J"],["K"]]
// would LIKE it to work like this
    gaussianCurve = []
    gaussianCurve.push(["A"])
    gaussianCurve.push(["B", "C"])
    gaussianCurve.push(["D", "E", "F", "G", "H"])
    gaussianCurve.push(["I", "J"])
    gaussianCurve.push(["K"])

    return  gaussianCurve
}
```

Why would I want such a thing? Progress bars.

1. They don’t show I am making progress immediately

   1. This is because the first job must complete before the bar can move
2. They slow down at 95%+ and sometimes even stick at 100%

   1. Just annoying

Any suggestions are welcome. I am just not seeing the answer in my minds eye.

EDIT: I feel it was worded poorly, so I am rewording it.

...gaussianCurve[0].length & gaussianCurve[gaussianCurve.length - 1].length would be 1, and gaussianCurve[gaussianCurve.length/2].length would be up to "maxArrayLength".

INPUT:

```
function gaussianRefactor(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"], 1)
function gaussianRefactor(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"], 2)
function gaussianRefactor(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"], 4)
function gaussianRefactor(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"], 8)
function gaussianRefactor(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"], 16)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[["A"],["B"],["C"],["D"],["E"],["F"],["G"],["H"],["I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A"],["B","C"],["D","E"],["F","G"],["H","I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A"],["B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"],["I","J","K"]]
[["A"],["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"],["J","K"]]
[["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]]
```

No inner array may exceed the length of maxArrayLength

Comment: If the above array contains two more letters i.e `L,M` then what will be the output?

Comment: I named the variable "maxArrayLength" to indicate it only provides an upper bound. If your array were of a number of elements that were less than the maxArrayLength parameter, it would basically be meaningless. An array like the one you provided could then be plugged into the answer provided by mike.k to get [[L],[M]] or [[L,M]]. Either would be fine. However, I would short circuit this in production code to say if (oneDimentionalArray.length <= maxArrayLength) return [oneDimentionalArray]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more inline with what I was thinking. I greatly dislike the way I am finding sigma. I know I should just reorder the formula to calculate it, but I have yet to get that to work. Anyway, here is the, "answer" though it fails for the smaller arrays I provided as examples in the question, it successfully does what I needed to do. If anyone has improvements they'd like to add, just let me know.

```
var gaussianRefactor = function(srcOneDimentionalArray, srcMaxArrayLength) {
  var finalArray = [];
  if (srcOneDimentionalArray.length <= srcMaxArrayLength) {
    finalArray.push(srcOneDimentionalArray);
    return finalArray;
  }
  if (srcMaxArrayLength === 1) {
  for(var lengthOne = 0; lengthOne < srcOneDimentionalArray.length; lengthOne++)
    finalArray.push([srcOneDimentionalArray[lengthOne]]);
    return finalArray;
  }
  var maxArrayLength = srcMaxArrayLength;
  var oneDimentionalArray = srcOneDimentionalArray.slice(0);
  for (var x = srcMaxArrayLength; x > 1 && maxArrayLength / oneDimentionalArray.length > 0.3333; x--) {
    maxArrayLength--;
  }
  var standardChunkSize = srcOneDimentionalArray.length / maxArrayLength;
  var predictedSize = (3 * Math.floor(standardChunkSize)) % 2 === 0 ? 3 * Math.floor(standardChunkSize) + 1 : 3 * Math.floor(standardChunkSize);
  var predictedSizeCenter = Math.ceil(predictedSize / 2);
  var sigma = 0.2034185 * Math.pow(standardChunkSize, 1.963449);
  var multiplicand = 1 / (Math.sqrt(sigma) * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI));
  var centerGauss = maxArrayLength / multiplicand;
  var mu = 0;
  var delta;
  var fraction;
  var exponent;
  var full;
  var subArrayLength;
  var subArray;
  var notWideEnough = true;
  var maxElements;
  var maxAttempts = Math.max(Math.ceil(sigma), 100);
  var currentAttempts = 0;
  while (notWideEnough && currentAttempts < maxAttempts) {
    maxElements = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < predictedSize; j++) {
      delta = (j - predictedSizeCenter) - mu;
      fraction = delta / Math.sqrt(sigma);
      exponent = -0.5 * Math.pow(fraction, 2);
      full = multiplicand * Math.exp(exponent);
      subArrayLength = Math.floor(full * centerGauss);
      maxElements += subArrayLength;
    }
    if (maxElements >= srcOneDimentionalArray.length) {
      notWideEnough = false;
    } else {
      sigma = sigma + sigma * 0.05;
    }
    currentAttempts++;
  }
  if (currentAttempts === maxAttempts) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < predictedSize; i++) {
    delta = (i - predictedSizeCenter) - mu;
    fraction = delta / Math.sqrt(sigma);
    exponent = -0.5 * Math.pow(fraction, 2);
    full = multiplicand * Math.exp(exponent);
    subArrayLength = Math.floor(full * centerGauss);
    if (subArrayLength < 1 || oneDimentionalArray.length < 1) {
      continue;
    }
    subArray = oneDimentionalArray.slice(0, subArrayLength);
    oneDimentionalArray = oneDimentionalArray.slice(subArrayLength, oneDimentionalArray.length);
    finalArray.push(subArray);
  }
  return finalArray;
}
```

INPUT

```
gaussianRefactor(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 1)
gaussianRefactor(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 2)
gaussianRefactor(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 4)
gaussianRefactor(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 8)
gaussianRefactor(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 16)
```

OUTPUT

```
[["A"],["B"],["C"],["D"],["E"],["F"],["G"],["H"],["I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A"],["B"],["C"],["D"],["E"],["F","G"],["H"],["I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A"],["B"],["C","D"],["E","F","G"],["H","I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A"],["B"],["C","D"],["E","F","G"],["H","I"],["J"],["K"]]
[["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]]
```

-- EDIT 2021 --
https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatter_og/xzfwjeaq/
I found the answer I was seeking. I will put it here if anyone is interested.

```
function removeMeFromTheList(removeMe, theList) {
  for (let i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
    if (theList[i] === removeMe) {
      theList.splice(i, 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}

function makeListOfGaussianLists(chunkWeights, objects) {
  const listOfLists = [];
  const chunkWeightsSize = Object.keys(chunkWeights).length;
  if (chunkWeightsSize < 1 || objects.length < chunkWeightsSize) {
    console.info("chunkWeights.length:" + chunkWeightsSize + " - objects.length:" + objects.length);
    return null;
  }
  const elementCount = objects.length / chunkWeightsSize;
  let modifiedElementCount = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < chunkWeightsSize; i++) {
    modifiedElementCount = parseInt(chunkWeights[i] * elementCount);
    let innerList = [];
    for (let j = modifiedElementCount; j > 0; j--) {
      const obj = objects[0];
      if (obj == null) {
        break;
      }
      innerList.push(obj);
      removeMeFromTheList(obj, objects);
    }
    listOfLists.push(innerList);
  }
  if (objects.length > 0) {
    do {
      for (let i = 0; i < listOfLists.length; i++) {
        const obj = objects[0];
        if (obj == null) {
          break;
        }
        listOfLists[i].push(obj);
        removeMeFromTheList(obj, objects);
      }
    } while (objects.length > 0);
  }
  return listOfLists;
}

function subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount) {
  const gauss = [];
  const population = 250;
  const chunkWeights = {};
  if (partitionCount > population) {
    return chunkWeights;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < population * 2; i++) {
    gauss.push(randomGaussian());
  }
  gauss.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  const partitionWidth = gauss.length / partitionCount;
  let currentCount = 0;
  let chunkWeightsIndex = 0;
  let pastTheFirst = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < gauss.length; j++) {
    if (currentCount < partitionWidth) {
      chunkWeights[chunkWeightsIndex] = 1 / (Math.abs(gauss[j]) + 0.66);
    } else {
      chunkWeightsIndex++;
      currentCount = 0;
    }
    currentCount++;
  }
  let offset = 0;
  for (let key in chunkWeights) {
    offset += chunkWeights[key];
  }
  offset /= partitionCount;
  offset = (1 - offset) + Number.MIN_VALUE;
  for (let key in chunkWeights) {
    let value = chunkWeights[key];
    chunkWeights[key] = value + offset;
  }
  return chunkWeights;
}

function randomGaussian() {
  let r = 0;
  const iteration = 6;
  for (let i = iteration; i > 0; i--) {
    r += Math.random();
  }
  return r / iteration - 0.5;
}

function pressButton() {
  let partitionCount = 23;
  console.info(makeListOfGaussianLists(subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount), makeRandomString(333).split("")));
  partitionCount = 41;
  console.info(makeListOfGaussianLists(subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount), makeRandomString(666).split("")));
  partitionCount = 67;
  console.info(makeListOfGaussianLists(subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount), makeRandomString(1000).split("")));
  partitionCount = 41;
  console.info(makeListOfGaussianLists(subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount), makeRandomString(1333).split("")));
  partitionCount = 23;
  console.info(makeListOfGaussianLists(subListWeightBuilder(partitionCount), makeRandomString(1666).split("")));
}

function makeRandomString(size) {
  const loops = parseInt(size / 11);
  let theResult = "";
  for(let i = loops; i > 0; i--) {
    theResult += Array(11 + 1).join((Math.random().toString(36) + '00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, 11);
  }
  return theResult += Array((size - 11 * loops) + 1).join((Math.random().toString(36) + '00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, (size - 11 * loops))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a quick shot and it seems to work. Some potential improvements:

- Input checking for the functions
- It places any possible leftover values into the middle bin. For even-numbered total bins it would benefit from some balancing. After that, it might be good to attempt to sort each bin based on the original index in the input data, since right now things can end up out of order. But if this is just to have non-linearly distributed jobs for a progress bar, the order may not matter.

```js
function probability(s, m, x) {
 var eExp = -Math.pow(x - m, 2) /
  (2 * Math.pow(s, 2));
 return 1/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI) * s) *
  Math.pow(Math.E, eExp);
}

function gassianArray(input, nBins) {
 // first try to determine a reasonable value of s so that the outer bins have a value
 var s = 0.1;
 var sMax = 10;
 var m = (nBins - 1) / 2.0;
 var outerBinMinimum = 1 / input.length;
 var p = 0;
 while (true && s <= sMax) {
  p = probability(s, m, 0);
  if (p >= outerBinMinimum) {
   break;
  } else {
   s += 0.1;
  }
 }

 // holds arrays
 var output = [];
 // holds desired array sizes
 var outputLengths = [];
 // fill these based on probability density
 for (var b=0; b<nBins; b++) {
  var n = Math.floor(probability(s, m, b) * input.length);
  output.push([]);
  outputLengths.push(n);
 }

 // fill arrays from outside, leaving extra values for the middle
 var midIndex = Math.floor(m);
 // left side
 for (var i=0; i<midIndex; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<outputLengths[i]; j++) {
   output[i].push(input.shift());
  }
 }
 // right side
 for (var i=nBins-1; i>=midIndex; i--) {
  for (var j=0; j<outputLengths[i]; j++) {
   output[i].push(input.pop());
  }
  output[i].reverse();
 }
 // whatever remains goes in the "middle"
 while (input.length !== 0) {
  output[midIndex].unshift(input.pop());
 }

 return output;
}

var input = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];
var n = 5;
console.log(gassianArray(input, n));
/*
[ [ 'A' ],
  [ 'B', 'C' ],
  [ 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H' ],
  [ 'I', 'J' ],
  [ 'K' ] ]
*/


var input = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var n = 6;
console.log(gassianArray(input, n));
/*
[ [ 'A' ],
  [ 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ],
  [ 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N' ],
  [ 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U' ],
  [ 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y' ],
  [ 'Z' ] ]
*/
```

Comment: "The array within ...[0] & ...[n-1] would be of length 1, and ...[n/2] would be a maximum provided by a parameter"

The "n" you provide is the maximum any array may be. If a GET can handle at most 50 values before it goes beyond the max char count. You would "chunk" your arrays in to X<=50 length. The request here is to have more arrays than the normal chunking would produce while following a gaussian curve. This is the non-trivial part. ...and the part that has me losing sleep.

That said, I LOVE what you have made here. So much better than my own first attempt. Brovo Zulu

Comment: @brightmatter thanks for the feedback. It might just be late (here) but I'm not sure I follow everything exactly. Would you mind posting an example of the "non-trivial" part with sample input and desired output?

Comment: I'll drop in a jsfiddle to the question above. It is not the answer to the question. It is just a way I was experimenting with to solve it with a triangular shape first. Not sure this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting challenge. :)

I have played a bit and here is what I came up with:

```js
function chunk(arr, start, n) {
  if (arr.length < n) {
    return null;
  }

  return arr.splice(start, n);
}

function gaussianArray(arr, max) {
  const len = arr.length;

  if (max > len) {
    return [arr];
  }

  const curve = [];

  // Extract middle.
  const mid = Math.floor(len / 2);
  const startIndex = mid - (max / 2) + 1;
  const highest = arr.splice(startIndex, max);

  curve.push(highest);

  // Splits the rest in 2 arrays; left side and right side, middle already excluded.
  const leftArr = arr.slice(0, startIndex);
  const rightArr = arr.slice(startIndex, len);

  let leftMax = max;
  let rightMax = max;

  // Adds chunks from left side.
  while (leftArr.length) {
    const leftChunk = chunk(leftArr, leftArr.length - leftMax, leftMax);

    if (leftChunk) {
      curve.unshift(leftChunk);
    } else {
      leftMax--;
    }
  }

  // Adds chunks from right side.
  while (rightArr.length) {
    const rightChunk = chunk(rightArr, 0, rightMax);

    if (rightChunk) {
      curve.push(rightChunk);
    } else {
      rightMax--;
    }
  }

  return curve;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(gaussianArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(gaussianArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(gaussianArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 4)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(gaussianArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 8)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(gaussianArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"], 16)));
```

It is not exactly what you want, but I think it should be close to solve your progress bar problem...

Comment: More realistic numbers would be 10,000 elements in the array 'chunked' into arrays having no more than 75 elements.

You want them to get hooked on the idea of waiting; to feel invested, so they don't abandon the request. Your code gives this initial 0.08% progress then goes right into the slowdown. I have something similar here: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatter_og/xzfwjeaq/
My example is no better, it gives 0.75% lead-in over the first 3 arrays. You want the progress bar to slowly get the the hard wait for any heavy request. Then, at the end it speeds up as a reward for being patient.

Comment: I see... and I perfectly understand what the problem is... Unfortunately I am not that good at math... But I will try to understand the normal distribution of gauss and retry to implement this, because it is indeed a very interesting problem... Thanks.